# How can I make NDSolve aware of vectorial nature of an ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, tensors, vector-calculus

I am trying to solve the equilibrium equation $\text{DIV } \mathbf P(\textbf{u}(x,y)) = \mathbf{f}$, where $\mathbf P$ is the stress tensor defined by

$$
    \mathbf P = \mathbf F + (1-\det\mathbf F)^2\quad\text{with}\quad \mathbf F = \text{GRAD } \mathbf u + \mathbf I.
$$

I implemented the equations above in Mathematica as follows

```
ns[x,y] = {nx[x,y], ny[x,y]};
F = Inactive[Grad][ns[x,y], {x,y}] + IdentityMatrix[2];
J = Det[F] //FullSimplify;
μ = 10;
λ = 5;

P = λ F + μ (1 - J)^2

solInt = y * x^2;
equation = Inactive[Div][P, {x, y}] == Inactive[Grad][solInt, {x, y}] ;
boundaryConds1 = {ns[x, y] == {3, 0}};
boundaryConds2 = {ns[x, y] == {0, 0}};
boundaryConds3 = {ns[x, y] == {0, 0}};

Ω = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}]
un = NDSolveValue[{equation,
   { 
      DirichletCondition[boundaryConds1, x == 1],
      DirichletCondition[boundaryConds2, x == 0],
      DirichletCondition[boundaryConds3, y == 0]
    }}, ns[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

This gives me the error:

> "There are more dependent variables, {nx[x, y], ny[x, y]}, than
> equations, so the system is underdetermined."

I suspect that the culprit is the fact that Mathematica does not understand that the equation, once evaluated, will yield a vector with two entries.

Any way to fix the issue?

Comment: According to this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/148529/74782), I indeed need to do something of the sort. However, they don't expose *how* it can be done.

Comment: You are using vector operators like Grad and Div. However, you set them all to:  inactive. If they do not act, you have only 1 equation, not a vector equation. Then NDSolve complains that you have 1 equation and 2 dependent variables.

Comment: It looks like `NDSolve` resists to solve this kind of equations.

Comment: @DanielHuber, yes they are set to inactive. However, if they are left as active, NDSolve is not able to create the weak form necessary to calculate the answer. If I run this script without the Inactive, `The maximum derivative order of the nonlinear PDE coefficients for the Finite Element Method is larger than 1. It may help to rewrite the PDE in inactive form.`.

Comment: I do not know a good answer to this. But have you seen: "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197046/ndsolve-error-what-does-it-may-help-to-rewrite-the-pde-in-inactive-form-mean" and "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195477/how-do-i-use-the-new-nonlinear-finite-element-in-mathematica-12-for-this-equatio/195481#195481". If nothing helps I would write a message to support@wolfram,com